# Drop Down in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to have one link pull from a table with a certain value and an identical link pull from the same table but different value.But both drop downs are appearing in the link.

[image]

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
        <select    style="width:350px;" name="featuredname" >
        <?php
        $selectunfeatured=mysql_query("select * from `properties` where `featured`='0' and `block`='0' and `active`='1' and `type`='1'");

        while($selectunfeaturedarray=mysql_fetch_array($selectunfeatured))
        {
        echo '<option value='.$selectunfeaturedarray['property_id'].'>'.$selectunfeaturedarray['property_title'].'</option>';
        }
        ?>
```

**Model:**

```
                <select    style="width:350px;" name="featuredname" >
        <?php
        $selectunfeatured=mysql_query("select * from `properties` where `featured`='0' and `block`='0' and `active`='1' and `type`='2'");

        while($selectunfeaturedarray=mysql_fetch_array($selectunfeatured))
        {
        echo '<option value='.$selectunfeaturedarray['property_id'].'>'.$selectunfeaturedarray['property_title'].'</option>';
        }
        ?>

        </select>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, I have two buttons, one to add a male model and selecting from a table to show the males. And the other button is to add a female model. But for some reason both buttons have two drop downs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as You performing identical operations in both `<select>` elements I would suggest You to make one function to extract all the data You need by passing `type` value as function parametr:

```
<?php
function getData($type){
    $db=mysql_connect('database_host','database_user','database_pass');
    mysql_select_db('database_name',$db);    
    $selectunfeatured = mysql_query("select * from `properties` where `featured`='0' and `block`='0' and `active`='1' and `type`='$type'");    
    while ($selectunfeaturedarray = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectunfeatured)) {
        $data[] = $selectunfeaturedarray;
    }    
    return $data;
}
?>
```

and to generate `<option>` element's do as follows:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <select style="width:350px;" name="featuredname[male]">
        <?php foreach(getData(1) as $male):?>
            <option value="<?=$male['property_id'];?>"><?=$male['property_title'];?></option>        
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </select> 

    <select style="width:350px;" name="featuredname[female]">
        <?php foreach(getData(2) as $female):?>
            <option value="<?=$female['property_id'];?>"><?=$female['property_title'];?></option>        
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>   
</div>
```

**NOTE:** In your example, both `select` elements have identical `name` attributes. In this case only selected value of the second `select` will be saved. If you want to get both of them then You have to put square bracket `[]`
in the end of each `name` attribute value `name="featuredname[]"` or `name="featuredname[male]"` && `name="featuredname[female]"`